# Mysql query dropping a zero. Getting (eg) £75.5 instead of £75.50?

Tags: mysql

I have been researching/trying to fix this since my first question... The query is dropping the trailing '0' in the total column.  I've tried `AS DECIMAL` and `FORMAT` without success - I'm guessing I'm putting brackets in the wrong place??

```
SELECT start_date AS 
START , end_date AS 
STOP , Activity, TIME_FORMAT( TIMEDIFF( end_date, start_date ) ,  '%h %i' ) AS Hours, CONCAT(  '£', rate ) AS Rate, CONCAT(  '£', FORMAT( TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
MINUTE , start_date, end_date ) * ( rate /60 ) , 2 ) ) AS Amount, 
COMMENT , CONCAT(  '£', expenses ) AS Expenses, CONCAT(  '£', FORMAT( TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
MINUTE , start_date, end_date ) * ( rate /60 ) , 2 ) + expenses ) AS total
FROM hours
JOIN activities ON hours.Activity = activities.description
WHERE Activity !=  "Caravan Park"
ORDER BY  `hours`.`end_date` DESC
```

Above is the code - does everything I want except display total column correctly.  That's not entirely true - how do I use `SUM()` to get a column total of the computed column 'total'.  That solution eluding me to!

Exceptionally grateful for all responses....

Comment: Please also feel free to identify all the inefficiency in the above code....

Comment: What exactly is your problem? `75.5` is the same as `75.50` Formatting should be done in the frontend not in the SQL query.

Comment: fair point, however the field is holding a currency value so I hoped for a method of presenting via the query a representation of that fact.